# morris.js horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

is it possible add horizontal bar chart with morris.js?

http://jsbin.com/uzosiq/2/embed?javascript,live

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick perusal of the [morris.js](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/) website shows no evidence of support for horizontal bar charts.

A Google search "horizontal bar charts javascript" shows a number of possible candidates including this one : http://www.rgraph.net/examples/hbar.html

Comment: Error 404: File Not found

Answer (score 4):

If you use morris from https://github.com/JelteF/morris.js
it is possible to see horizontal graphs.

Working example given in issue # [455](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/pull/455) is - http://jsbin.com/pucadowa/8/edit?js,output

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is,
but a lot of code have to be written
check this 
[enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/pucadowa/8/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
/*
 * Play with this code and it'll update in the panel opposite.
 *
 * Why not try some of the options above?
 */
/* @license
morris.js v0.5.0
Copyright 2014 Olly Smith All rights reserved.
Licensed under the BSD-2-Clause License.
*/
/* @license
morris.js v0.5.1
Copyright 2014 Olly Smith All rights reserved.
Licensed under the BSD-2-Clause License.
*/
(function(){var a,b,c,d,e=[].slice,f=function(a,b){return function(){return .......}).call(this);


Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B'],
  horizontal: true,
  stacked: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but you can try

> http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php

or

> http://www.jscharts.com

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for an updated version of morris then check out this forked version of the original one [morrisjs version 6](https://github.com/pierresh/morris.js)

Plus it is way much better and updated !